# Validar Datos en c++

Tags: c++, c, números-enteros, validación

Necesito validar la entrada numérica de datos en c++, estoy utilizando:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int dato;
    cout<<"Ingrese un valor para dato: ";

    while( ( cin>>dato ).fail() ) { //comprobamos los flags de error con la referencia que devuelve el operador >>
        cin.clear(); //reseteamos los flags
        fflush(stdin); //limpio buffer de entrada
        cout<<".:Entrada Invalida:."<<endl;
        cout<<"Ingrese un valor para dato: ";  
    }

    cout<<"\n\tEl Dato es: "<<dato;

    return 0;
}
```

Esto funciona correctamente para entradas de un carácter y cadenas, también para cadenas Alpha-Numéricas pero solo cuando los números son ingresados después de un carácter .

Ejemplo:

```
Ingrese un valor para dato: t
.:Entrada Invalidada:.
Ingrese un valor para dato: ttt
.:Entrada Invalidada:.
Ingrese un valor para dato: rgwsw934954
.:Entrada Invalidada:.
```

Si pongo una entrada como 3x donde primero ingreso un numero y luego los caracteres, este toma como respuesta 3, pero necesito que pida de nuevo un dato.

```
Ingrese un valor para dato: 1234qwerty

    El Dato es: 1234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La entrada formateada tiene esa *ligera molestia*: Si el principio de la cadena leida **concuerda** con lo esperado, se toman los datos necesarios y se deja el resto en el *buffer*.

Si lo que quieres es asegurarte de que la entrada **completa** tiene solo números, tendrás que comprobarlo tu mismo:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( ) {
  string str; // Cadena leída
  int dato;

  cout << "Ingrese un valor para dato: ";

  while( getline( cin, str ) ) {
    const char *idx = str.c_str( );

    // Mientras que no lleguemos al final de la cadena,
    // y el caracter sea un dígito.
    while( *idx && *idx >= '0' && *idx <= '9' )
      ++idx;

    // Si llegamos al final de la cadena, la validación es correcta.
    if( !( *idx ) )
      break;

    cout << "Entrada inválida.\n";
  }

  // Convertimos la cadena en entero.
  dato = atoi( str.c_str( ) );
  // Y lo mostramos.
  cout << "El dato es: " << dato << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

El código anterior comprueba que la entrada **sean solo dígitos**. **No tiene en cuenta** el tamaño de la entrada, ni tampoco un posible signo `-` para indicar un número negativo.

Comment: Hola, creo que deberías indicar también que si el valor ingresado es inválido, al convertir `dato` por medio de la función `atoi`, el resultado que sale es `0`.