# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se inserten letras o cadenas de textos en entradas de datos de tipo entero?

Tags: c++, entrada

Si tengo una entrada de datos de tipo entero, y el usurio ingresa una letra o una cadena de caracteres, quisiera que aparezca un mensaje diciendo: "valor no valido", ayuda por favor :'(

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int num;
    cout<<"Inserte un numero"<<endl;
    cin>>num;
    cout<<"Su numero es: "<<num;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Que pasa si ingresas Letras encambio de numeros?

Comment: Tal vez este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/109552/validar-datos-en-c) pueda servirte.

Comment: @4lrdyD Gracias, era justo lo que estaba buscando, te estoy infinitamente agradecido por mostrarme el post, jajaja